# Codeigniter Database backup not returning readable file

Tags: database, codeigniter, backup, codeigniter-2

This my controller function in which i used database util library to crate backup for database. When i download a backup the zip file cannot be opened with zip extractor. What should I do?

```
function backup_database() {

        $file_name = 'accounts';
        $date = date('@Y.m.d-H.ia');

        $name = $file_name . $date;

        // Load the DB utility class
        $this->load->dbutil();

        // Backup entire database and assign it to a variable
        $backup = & $this->dbutil->backup(array('filename' => "$name.sql"));

        // Load the file helper and write the file to server
        $this->load->helper('file');
        write_file("$name.zip", $backup);

        // Load the download helper and send the file to desktop
        $this->load->helper('download');
        force_download("$name.zip", $backup);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a function I use, to perform a database backup.

```
function _backup_db()
{
    $this->load->dbutil();
    $this->load->helper(array('file', 'download')); 

    $backup =& $this->dbutil->backup();

    $filename = 'backup-' . time() . ' .zip';

    write_file('/backups/' . $filename, $backup);
    force_download($filename, $backup); 
}
```

The only thing I can notice that's different is the file name in the backup() function. According to the user guide, you only need to add the file name to the backup() array, if it's a .zip file.

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/utilities.html#backup

Comment: Quote:  _"you only need to add the file name to the backup() array, if it's a .zip file"_ ~ Isn't that what the OP is already doing?

Comment: No. He is using "$name.sql"